# Can an NSMutableOrderedSet<NSString*> be sorted using an NSSortComparator?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Before instantly assuming this is a duplicate, read on.

I want to sort a large `NSMutableOrderedSet<NSString*>` in an efficient manner.

I know how to sort an `NSMutableOrderedSet<SomeObject*>` using `NSSortComparator` and setting the key to the relevant member of `SomeObject`.

I also know how to sort an array of `SomeObject` using `sortUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject).`

I also know how to sort an array of, for example, `NSNumber` using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)`

But what I can't figure out is how to sort an `NSMutableOrderedSet` when the items are native Obj-C objects such as NSString as opposed to user defined objects:

- `NSortComparator` uses a key, however there is no key if the set contents is an `NSString` as opposed to a custom object? So this can't be used? (I notice `NSSortComparator` has a `SEL` property and I therefore thought it might be possible to set it to `NSString:compare`, but its read only).
- I have found sorting a large array (say about 50,000 items) using `sortUsingComparator` is slow (a few seconds) but sorting an `NSMutableOrderedSet` containing the same type of elements is virtually instantaneous using `NSSortComparator`. Therefore I do not want to sort using sortUsingComparator if slow.
- I can't see a method of `NSMutableOrderedSet` such as `sortedArrayUsingSelector`.

So my question is how can I sort the set in an efficient way if I can't use a `sortDescriptor` and if `sortUsingComparitor` is slow?

I could create a `DummyObject` containing nothing but an `NSString` and have `NSMutableOrderedSet<DummyObject*>` and then sort using `NSSortComparator`, but that seems crazy, so there must be a simpler way, but I can't see what that is from the API nor documentation nor past questions.

Comment: @rmaddy no it isn't.  If strings such as "xxx", "aaa", "ddd" for example are adding using addObject in that order,and  then if the set is iterated over, then they are in the same order as when added. The set is not ordered automatically on addition of a string. Using setObject:atIndex would ensure ordering on insertion but that is not part of my question, I want to know how to sort them after using addObject.

Comment: You should be able to pass `@"self"` as the key to the sort descriptor.  I think `nil` works too.

Comment: @ChromiumDioxide Oops. Momentary lapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableOrderedSet<NSString*> *set =  [[NSMutableOrderedSet<NSString*> alloc] init];
[set addObject:@"c"];
[set addObject:@"b"];
[set addObject:@"a"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
[set sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]
```